flutter: get html content from webview at web app
Both flutter_inappwebview and webview_flutter_web packages lack returning the html content from the rendered web view.
At the flutter_inappwebview, adding this snippet at the example app returns the html content both at iOS and Android, but not at Chrome, which html is null:
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.html),
                onPressed: () async {
                  final html2 = await webViewController?.getHtml();
                  print('html2 = $html2');
                },
              )

The same behavior happens at native webview from Flutter SDK don't have the addJavascriptChannel function implemented. Getting the content at iOS and Android works, but not for web/chrome.
Is there any way of scrapping or getting the html content from a website using Dart or Flutter?

The issue with using Flutter to fetch HTML content from a website is that you might encounter CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) restrictions. These restrictions prevent your web application from accessing resources on a different domain due to security policies.
A straightforward solution is to use a proxy server. A proxy server fetches the content on behalf of your application, thereby avoiding CORS restrictions. While there are lists of free proxy servers available, they often come with limitations on the number of calls and might occasionally go offline. Therefore, you might need to host your own proxy server.
Here’s an example of how to use a proxy server to fetch HTML content:
Future<void> fetchHtmlContent() async {
  // This is fake proxy url you need to find a real one.
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://proxy-server-example.com?url=https://example.com'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var htmlContent = response.body;
  } else {
    // Handle error
  }
}

